# SCORM file that launches website using URL

Tags: html, url, scorm

We are currently using an LMS system for an online course. Almost all of our material is online. We are starting to SCORM format our online material. Instead of attempting to physically merge all of our HTML pages within a SCORM file, isn't there a way to simply have the SCROM file launch a given URL automatically? All of our material needs to be in SCORM format in order for our LMS system to track the time spent in our LMS course which is why we are making the switch.

Is there a way to instantiate this in the manifest.xml or launchpage.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some companies including mine, use a local file which launches a frameset to our websites. The SCORM runtime communication between the two sites can happen using a HTML5 postmessage. For example, if a learner gets a score on your website, you can send the information to the code that sits in that small local file on the LMS. In turn, you call SCORM runtime from the that file. This can also happen in reverse. Here's an example by Claude Ostyn:

http://www.ostyn.com/standardswork/xdomain/remotecontentdemo.htm

Comment: thanks for sharing. any idea where this demo moved to? appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

At minimum if you can run the base index.html file and point your CSS and JavaScript to your content server or CDN that would solve the double IFRAME or trying to get around browser security due to X-domain issues with your domain trying to access the LMS's runtim API on their domain.

This does cause a obvious authoring challenge or at minimum a massive search and replace in files on your project.

Only other way still requires the IFRAME workaround to get around it.